# Continuous image of a Polish space to another has the Baire property

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, polish-spaces

Here's a theorem in the course notes of a course on Polish groups:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Polish spaces and $f:X\to Y$ continuous.
>
> $f(X)$ has the Baire property.

In the course note, it's written that this follows from the existence of $U(A)$ (which I define bellow). The proof should be easy otherwise I would have written it. Unfortunately, while reviewing the notes, I forgot the proof and I'm unable to prove the theorem above.

Here's the definition of $U(A)$:

> Let $X$ be a Polish space and $A\subseteq X$.
>
> $$U(A):=\bigcup\{O\mid A\text{ is comeager in $O$, i.e, $O\backslash A$ is meager}\}.$$

We have the following facts:

> 1. $U(A)$ is open.
> 2. $A$ is comeager in $U(A)$.
> 3. $A$ has the Baire property $\iff$ $A\backslash U(A)$ is meager.

**Attempt**

So I tried to show that $f(X)\backslash U(f(X))$ is meager.

If $f(X)$ is meager, we're done. Otherwise $U(f(X))\neq\emptyset$ and $U(f(X))\backslash f(X)$ is meager. I coudln't find a way to use the continuity of $f$ to conclude. I also tried to prove the theorem by contradiction using $$f(X)\backslash U(f(X))=\bigcap\{f(X)\backslash O\mid f(X)\text{ is comeager in $O$}\}$$

but I couldn't get to the result. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Polish spaces and $f:X\to Y$ continuous.
>   $f(X)$ has the Baire property.

This is Nikodym’s or Luzin-Sierpiński’s theorem stating that analytic sets have Baire property. Its proofs which I found  are not very easy but are based on previous lemmas like closedness of a class of sets with Baire property under Souslin operation. See, for instance, Proposition 3.26 in “[Lecture notes on descriptive set theory](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/ag/logik/teaching/2013SS/advanced%20topics/Lecture%20notes%20on%20descriptive%20set%20theory%20June.pdf)” by Philipp Schlicht, [Lecture on Regularity Properties of Analytic Sets](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jsr25/Spring_11/Lecture_Notes/dst_lecture_notes_2011_Regularity-Analytic.pdf) or Corollary 14.5 in “[Introduction to descriptive set theory](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~anush/Teaching_notes/dst_lectures.pdf)” by Anush Tserunyan. See also Theorem 11.18.ii [here](http://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~hart/set_theory/Jech/11-Borel_and_analytic_sets.pdf) and Theorem 2.2 in “[Analytic Baire spaces](http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/adam/Analytic%20Baire%20spaces.pdf)” by A. J. Ostaszewski.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So I guess my memory is confused and that we didn't prove the result during the class.

Comment: Also I allowed myself to edit the link to Tserunyan's lecture notes. I found in the older a typo (see (3) of Proposition 9.14), The new link should be the one that keeps up with the modifications.